# Search for a value in all Google Sheets at once

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-search

I have hundreds of spreadsheets in Google Drive and I am trying to find a value in one of the files.

[image: Google drive]

For example, I need to find all sheets that have a $1000 value, but I don't want to open each one of my spreadsheets.

[image: Value]

How can I search for a value in all of my Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done using the Google Drive search feature but it can be scripted using the Google Sheets API.

First you need to retrieve the [list of spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/worksheets#retrieve_a_list_of_spreadsheets) that you have access to. Next, you loop over those worksheet IDs and [perform a search](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data#send_a_structured_query_for_rows) within the rows, looking for the "$1000" value or anything else you want to find. If there is a matching row then you want to keep a copy of its ID and likely the parent spreadsheet ID. At the end you'll have a list of sheets that contain your search query.

This is probably not the answer you were hoping for. I'll see if I can dig up some existing code that someone put together for this exact task.

**Update:** if you want to code a solution that uses the API, check out this simple [Python library](https://github.com/burnash/gspread). The test files have examples of how one would get all their spreadsheets and search the sheets for some value. I would type out some code but I'm on vacation with just my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) that searches all of current user's spreadsheets. If you have  a lot of spreadsheets, it might time out of hit some execution quota, in which case it may be better to restrict it to a folder: replace `DriveApp.getFilesByType`  with

```
DriveApp.getFolderById('folder id here').getFilesByType
```

The value to search is entered on `var value =` line. Keep in mind that dollar sign in $1000 is just an element of formatting; the value is 1000.

The search results (Spreadsheet name and sheet name) are logged: press Ctrl-Enter to view the log after the script is finished.

---

Technical detail: the try-catch block is there because the sheets without data (chart only sheets) throw an error when one tries to access their DataRange.

```
function searchSpreadsheets() {
  var value = 314;   // the value to search for
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(files.next());
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      try {
        var values = flatten(sheets[i].getDataRange().getValues());
      }
      catch(e) {
        continue;
      }
      if (values.indexOf(value) != -1) {
        Logger.log('Spreadsheet ' + ss.getName() + ', sheet ' + sheets[i].getName()); 
      }
    }
  }
}

function flatten(arg) {
  return arg.reduce ? arg.reduce(function(a, b) {return a.concat(b);}) : [arg];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive allows you to do queries like:

https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=1000%20parent:GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID_HERE

1000 = querying value

%20 = space